# Creating a $3\times 3$ matrix $X$ from a $3\times 3$ matrix with only $2$ eigen values?

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok, so I hope I can explain this right. I have a matrix $A$:

[image]

I took $\det((A-XI))$ and found the eigen values to be $-1$ and $2$.

I need to construct a $3\times 3$ invertible matrix from the eigen vectors, however, I am unsure how this works, since I only have 2 eigen values, which would only yield $2$ eigen vectors.

In addition, I need to solve for $D = X^{-1} * A * X$. I tried making the third eigen vector a column of zeros, but the inverse of that is singular. I feel like I am inching further and further away from the correct way of solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a third vector, linearly independant from the other two, (try looking into generalised eigenvectors), and you create a $3\times 3$ matrix, which has columns as those eigenvectors.

Which is the repeated eigenvalue? I.e. multiplicity two.

Since the repeated eigenvalue is $\lambda=2$, what we do is we find a generalised eigenvector, which is done by solving:

$(A-\lambda I)^2v= 0\Rightarrow(A-2I)^2v=0$

And we solve this exactly like we would to find a standard eigenvector.

Comment: My question was pretty much asking how I found the values for the third eigen vector. So far, I have <-6,0,1>^T, <1,1/3,1>^T

Comment: Okay, I can explain, I just need to know which was the repeated eigenvalue?

Comment: 2 is the repeated eigenvalue.

Comment: okay I will add an edit.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. Is it supposed to be squared?

Comment: Yes it is, check this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector it explains generalised eigenvectors, they are used if you have a repeated eigenvalue.

Comment: I am reading it. In example one it states, .. "Then there is one eigenvalue λ=1 with an algebraic multiplicity m of 2." but it is not squared

Comment: The next line has $(A-\lambda I)^k$, for $k=1,2,...,n$, but in our case, $n=2$

Comment: Ok, so I took A from the OP minus a 3x3 where the diagonals are 2 and the rest of the numbers in the matrix are 0. I squared that, but I am not sure what I multiply or solve it for.

Comment: v1, v2 and = zero vector?

Comment: Okay, so you have calculated $(A-2I)^2$, now if you had calcualted $A-2I$, you would know what to do right? you solve $(A-2I)v=0$, (I've just realised the typo in what I've put in my answer, you should solve $(A-2I)^2v=0$ not $(A-2I)^2v=v$).
So do the same thing, but solve $(A-2I)^2v=0$

Comment: I am solving and multipling by v as [x;y;z] and equaling it to zero. However, my answer still seems wrong.

Comment: That is the correct method, what seems wrong?

Comment: I am not getting actual values, unless I am missing something obvious. y = z/3, z = 3y...

Comment: That is because eigenvectors are not unique, i.e you need $z=3y$, so just pick $y=1$ for example, then $z=3$, and you have the generalised eigenvector $(0,1,3)^T$ :)

Comment: But according to wolfram alpha, the eigen vector $(1,1/3,1)^T$ seems to be wrong. that eigen vector (which I believe corresponds to the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$) should just be $(1,0,0)$

Comment: Yes! I finally got it, however, I took a different approach to the way you stated. I was missing something obvious. When solving for the eigen vectors with the repeated eigen values, my free variables were incorrectly assigned, resulting in only 1 eigen vector. Because there are 2 free variables, I have 2 eigen vectors for 2 and then a single eigen vector from the third eigenvalue. I augmented these vectors into a 3x3 matrix and got the answer correct.

Comment: Brilliant, that is totally correct, what I gave is just an "algorithmic" way of calculating the other eigenvector :)

Comment: Sweet! Upvoting your answer for the help, thanks again!

Comment: no worries, happy to help :)